# How to make `plt.show()` responsive to ctrl-C?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

```
$ cat main.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

_, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
y = x
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
$ ./main.py
^C
```

The above program is not responsive to ctrl-C on Big Sur. Is there a way to make it responsive to ctrl-C? Thanks.

Comment: What is your environment?  I've tried your code on Windows and Ubuntu 18.04, and the Ctrl-C works just fine.  I assume closing the window allows the script to exit.

Comment: I use Big Sur. I just want to terminate the process instead of the terminal window.

Comment: What I meant is the plot window.  The `plt.show` command displays the plot in a window.  If you close that window, the script should end.

Comment: I want to use ctrl-C so that I don't have to touch my mouse. Close the plot window involves mouse click which I don't want to do.

Comment: Nonsense.  Running the script sets the focus to the plot window.  Pressing Cmd-W closes the window (as it usually does) and exits the script.

Comment: That is two issues. Sometimes when my focus is on the terminal, I want to close the plot without having to switch to the plot.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be adding the following to the beginning of your script:

```py
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

(Thanks to [fospald](https://gist.github.com/fospald) https://gist.github.com/djwbrown/3e24bf4e0c5e9ee156a5?permalink_comment_id=4128738#gistcomment-4128738)